# Load Once - Then Reload With New Data

Tags: jquery

I am experiencing issues with the following code. I have the page loading once and refreshing with the number specified.

The only problem is once you have changed to once, you can't then change the number and run it a second time. Any suggestions or code variations?

```
$(window).one( "load", function() {
 initReload();
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    lastUrl = document.referrer;
    if(lastUrl.indexOf("website") == -1) {
        $( ".anumber" ).each(function() { 
            $(this).html("0438 999 999");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: please explain with better detail. Can't change what? Can't run what? Well constructed clear and concise questions will get answered quickly here

Comment: I resolved this issue. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class was incorrect on the website. This code functions well.